# PHP whitescreen of death on perfectly good code

Tags: php, audio, video, download, youtube

So far I've only been messing around with javascript so, I have no idea how php works. I assume I've made some newbie mistake somewhere above which I can't fine.

Thank for the help!

```
<?php
require('youtube-dl.class.php');
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $url = $_POST['url'];
    try {
        new yt_downloader($url, TRUE, 'audio');
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
?>
```

The downloader incase that's important: https://github.com/eyecatchup/php-yt_downloader/

Comment: Turn on error reporting

Comment: [Use this for white screen of death...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: *"So far I've only been messing around with javascript so"* - What JS?

Comment: So if `submit` is NOT set, run the codez?

Comment: @AbraCadaver yeah, they like it when  code runs not. *Yoda talk*.

Comment: If the field 'submit' is posted the page will return nothing.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` perhaps? and make sure it's "named" and that the form does imply a POST method.